# AngularJS template depending on property

Tags: angularjs

When performing a `GET` request with Angular and getting a response, there's a list of objects with a property called `type`. Depending on this type (and sometimes other additional checks), I can predict the rest of the properties of the object. An example:

```
{ "type": "simpleObject", "name": "A Simple Object" }
{ "type": "objectWithInteger", "name": "Another Object", "number": 10 }
```

So when iterating through a list of these objects, how could I apply a predefined template in order to have an adequate HTML for each different objects?

For example, when the type is `"simpleObject"`, we would use a `simple-object.html` template. When it's `"objectWithInteger"`, a `object-with-integer.html` partial.

Can this be done? Maybe with a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)? I am not very experienced with Angular, and as far as I can understand this is not a usual scenario.

So, basically I'd want to be able to do something like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="object in objects">
    {{ appropriate_template(object) }}
  </li>
</<ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a template file for each type like this, by using [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-include="'/path/to/templates/'+object.type+'.html'">
  </li>
</<ul>
```

and then there are files like `simpleObject.html` where you have the according HTML, e.g. `objectWithInteger.html`:

```
Name: {{object.name}}, Number: {{object.number}}
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant answer. I wouldn't want to have html files with the exact `object.type` name but I guess I could make a method in my `app.js` file that returns the appropriate template file name given a type.

Comment: yeah, just make sure that the file exist then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the ng-switch and ng-include directives.

```
  <div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <div ng-switch="object.type">
      <div ng-switch-when="simpleObject">
        <ng-include src="'simpleObject.html'"></ng-include>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="objectWithInteger">
        <ng-include src="'objectWithInteger.html'"></ng-include>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/SIYRWZI4s32KnO4lAcwd)